# How to add 2560x1440 resolution in VMware?

Tags: linux, manjaro, vmware

I installed Manjaro using VMware. But I could not find 2560x1440 in the resolution list. How can I add it?

Found some answers online.

```
$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440"  241.500   2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-3 "2560x1440"
$ xrandr --output HDMI-3 --mode 2560x1440
```

I am using virtual machine. How do I know which HDMI I am using?

Comment: What does `xrandr` (from the VM) show you're connected to? I seriously doubt it will show **HDMI**.

Answer (score 0):

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
Virtual1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
```

You will likely have the same or a similar output if you're using a VM.

You can then add the resolution in the same way, but by using `Virtual1` as the name rather than HDMI-*. Like so:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440"  241.500   2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
$ xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "2560x1440"
$ xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 2560x1440
```